# How to compute setup cost and increment cost provided two quantities and prices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

- q is qty
- s is setup cost
- i is incremental cost
- u is unit cost
  $$
  u = \frac{s}{q} + i
  $$
  provided

u1 = 3.02000 q1 = 1000

u2 = 1.64710 q2 = 2500

I am trying to come up with a general formula for computing setup and incremental given two unit costs and quantities.

Comment: If I interpret this correctly, you have constants $s$ and $i$ and a function
$$
u(q) = \frac{s}{q} + i
$$
Then you know two values for this function, $u(q=1000) = 3.02$ and $u(q= 2500) = 1.6471$. If you plug these results in to the given equation, you get two linear equations from which you can solve for $s$  and $i$.

Comment: That's what i am trying to do.  I have substituted values but I need an equation as this is part of a program so I just want s = f(q1,u1,q2,u2) and 
i = f(q1,u1,q2,u2)

Comment: What are the two equations you get when you plug in the known values? Write them side by side. Now use linear algebra to solve for $s$ and $i$.

Comment: I apologize, If I knew how to do what you suggest I would not have asked the question.